# Tutorials for making personalized Android UI

Tags: android

I'm moderately new to Android. And have intentions of making beautiful apps

All these applications like IMDB, News-Applications, even app of google-play  have brilliant yet light UI.

I want to know from where a newbie like me can learn to build these kind of UI.
I googled but mostly found tutorials on basic layouts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See: [Stack Overflow is not your research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/157574).

Answer (score 5):

Couple of things you need to consider

1. As tyczj mentioned, you need to go through android docs for UI completely, atleast once.
2. The Apps are not designed just to look good but they are designed from a usability perspective. Take a look at this link: [40 beautiful android apps](http://android.appstorm.net/roundups/40-beautiful-android-application-interfaces-and-icons/)
   You will see how a UI looks apt from the application business perspective. This in general terms is called UX - User Experience. Try and think around these lines.

To get you started let us say that you wanted to build a simple app on recipes , The first thing you need to do is think what you want to show, lets say an animated splash screen (like a plate of noodles hitting the screen and the noodles on the screen sliding down due to gravity and then you app logo/name comes in), on launching the app and then you move to the actual screen.
Once you come up with a picture like this in your mind, there is a lot of help out there. Just Google splash screens, and then an animated splash screen, writing you own custom animation etc.

"Necessity is the god mother of all good things"!! So get cracking, get an idea, Google on how to implement it!!

Resources

- UI Kit -- http://speckyboy.com/2010/05/10/android-app-developers-gui-kits-icons-fonts-and-tools/?mobify=0
- Refer to Droid Draw from the above link
- Checkout the linked in app for Android for really cool inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

right [here](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html) gives android UI guidelines for making apps

Comment: thanks...but I also need tutorials

Comment: the tutorials are in the android docs you need to look